# xCode: Accessing properties of an object via console

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsobject

Is it possible to access the properties of objects in xCode console?

If I try the following I get an error that he property doesn't exist.

po someObject.someprop

If I don't breakpoint the code and run the app it works fine so I know someObject.someprop exists. I don't think I have the grasp on xCode console yet?  What I loved about Flex/Flash development is that I could set a break point and in the console window or variables view I could traverse every structure down to the ends of the earth.

I could see SomeDicionary[key].someArray[1].someObject.prop and it would show me the value.  Is this not possible in xCode console or is there a trick to get to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll actually have to use the bracket syntax notation:

```
po [someObject someprop]
```

The debugger is sometimes very finnicky about syntax. [This](http://nachbaur.com/blog/basics-xcode-debugging-tips) is filled with all sorts of helpful tips for debugging in XCode.

Just a side note, variables/properties declared in the implementation file (*.m) instead of the header file (*.h) can sometimes be invisible to the debugger variable list display depending on if the breakpoint is in that class's code, because of scope. Not necessarily required here, but useful to know seeing as how it is kind of relevant.